# Loop through multidimensional $_GET

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to loop through everything in a `$_GET` request or `$_POST` request?
I know it's possible to to do a `foreach` loop, but that doesn't **fully** include `Array` values.

What I want to do is sanitize every string inside of the `$_GET` or `$_POST` globals so they're ready for use in a Data `class`.

I also know I could do something like `foreach($user_data['permissions']...` but I'm not going to know everything that's in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables.

Comment: If item is array - loop through it in a nested `foreach`

Comment: Yes, but that will get messy very quickly and I won't always know if an array will be inside of another array etc... etc...

Answer (score 0):

[`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) may help you; however, it has one critical flaw:

> Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function.

That means that if you have something like this:

```
$_GET = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'permissions' => array(
        'abc' => 123
    )
);
```

You would see that `foo => bar` and `abc => 123`, but you'd have no idea that `permissions.abc => 123`. There's a chance this doesn't matter, if you just need to sanitize all of the values (independent of the [nested] keys). If this does matter, you may be better doing your own implementation. Something like this:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $sKey => $sValue) {
            // sanitize
        }
    } else {
        // sanitize
    }
}
```

This could even be turned into a function that could recursively loop forever, but I'll let that up to you. Essentially you would just put the above in a `sanitizeData()` function and then call that `sanitizeData()` function anytime the value of the array `is_array()`.